# How can I reset the PRAM if Recovery Mode keeps overriding the PRAM command?

Tags: macos, keyboard, startup, nvram

Lion uses the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to boot into recovery mode. Resetting the PRAM in anything less than 10.7 was <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Recovery mode now seems to override the PRAM command. Does anyone know if there is a new way to reset the PRAM now that Lion is installed?

Comment: It's a matter of timing. You need to push these key immediately after turning on. If you wait too long, the bootloader is already active, which uses Cmd+R for the recovery function.

Comment: If you have the option, try using a (different) external, wired keyboard. If the reset PRAM shortcut works, then maybe it's something with the original keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting the PRAM works the same way it always did.  This is a function of the hardware - not the OS.  What makes you think it doesn't work anymore?  (tested on Macbook, Mac Mini).

Comment: I tried it 4 times on my wife's MacBook and it booted into recovery mode each time.

Answer (score 3):

Nate , PRAM reset is not working because you turn on Password Firmware Protection.
Turn it off and P+R+Option+Command will work.

Answer (score 1):

Or she has spilt something on the keyboard and the shift key is telling the computer it's being held down, so no matter what, it will boot into recovery mode. I work for an apple specialist and see it all the time.